# sql server query 3 tables

Tags: sql-server

have 3 tables:
Users, Services and ActiveServices

in users and service are the customers and the services offered while in ActiveServices are listed the Services Activated by Each User

structure of tables is the following:

```
Users:
ID, UserID, Name, ...

Services:
ID, ServiceID, Enabled, Category, Price, ...

ActiveServices:
ID, UserID,ServiceID,PaidUntil,MaxUsers, ...
```

I need to build a query for the selected `UserID`

that shows **all** Services available, and if that Service is already Active (thus is present in ActiveServices and `date()<=PaidUntil` need to return

> "Active" and PaidUntil value

while if it is not yet Active (thus not present in ActiveServices table or if `PaidUntil< date()`, have to return

> "Activate"

I tried several queries but I'm quite far from the solution.. if can give me some hints..
thanks

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update #2**

After your last comment, I've turned back to using a left join, this time with a derived table:

```
declare @UserID varchar(50)='Ben'

SELECT s.*, 
       COALESCE ('Active until ' + CONVERT(char(10), PaidUntil, 103) 
               , 'Activate') As Active,
       months
       -- You can add whatever columns you need from Active services here
FROM Services s
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM ActiveServices 
  WHERE UID = @UserID
) a ON(s.ServiceID = a.ServiceID)
```

As you can see, I've eliminated the selection of services that other users registered in using the where condition in the derived table.
Actually, this is what I should have thought about first: Not only is the sql statement simpler, it should also have better performance then the one in the previous update. [See fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c88fb/11)

**Update #1**

Once I've had the sql fiddle, I was able to see the problem and fix it.
[See updated fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e90bb/18)
This query should return what you need:

```
SELECT s.*,
       COALESCE (
       (
        SELECT 'Active until ' + CONVERT(char(10), PaidUntil, 103)
        FROM ActiveServices a
        WHERE s.ServiceID = a.ServiceID
        AND  UID = @UserID
       ), 'Activate') As T
FROM Services s
```

I've traded the `left join` for an `sub query`, thus eliminating the need for `distinct` since we are only selecting from the *services* table, and eliminating the need for the `case` as well.

**First answer**

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*,
       CASE WHEN UserID = @UserID AND PaidUntil > GETDATE() THEN 
          'Active until ' + CONVERT(char(10), PaidUntil, 103) -- or any style you need
       ELSE
          'Activate'
       END As 
FROM Services s
LEFT JOIN ActiveServices as
ON(s.ServiceID = as.ServiceID)
```

Explanation:

- The [`Left join`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) means that you get every records from the `Services` table even if it doesn't have a matching record in the `ActiveServices` table.
- The [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) enables you to use if..then..else logic inside the sql statement
- The [`coalesce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is an SQL function that returns the first non-null value from the list of values it gets.
- The [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is an SQL function that converts data from one data type to another.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks, but.. WHERE statement does not work properly: if customer has not yet subscribed any service will return an empty recordset, while if I remove it, will show all active using casual PaidUntil value:
need to put the UserID filter somewhere within the "CASE" statement
But in your solution I've not been able to do it. while I succeed with Kamil and Karthik solutions.

Comment: See my edited answer. Adding the `userid is null or` part to the where clause should fix this problem.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for answering. I already tried to add UserID is null clause but does return only services not subscribed by anybody: if a service has been subscribed by any customer is not shown (since UserID is not null)

Comment: Hi, yes not it works.. but I've been too quick :-(
Testing a little deeper I found that all solution do not work properly:
if have more than 1 user that subscribe a certain Service I found it duplicated (or more) in the results:
I imagine that need to add a "distinct" somewhere but since the "CASE" field is specific.. probably this solution is not working:
with my poor knowledge I would try adding 4-5 Case When Statements, one for each field to output, although surely there is a better and more elegant solution.
I will try and let you know

@Zohar Peled

Comment: Are you sure? the only way I can think of something like that can happen is if your selected user registered more then once to a service. Is that the case?

Comment: No, each customer register only once to a service.
But the statement `left join users u on s.uid=u.uid` select all users not only @uid
If I can succeed will prepare a demo on jsfiddle and link to you later today
Thanks for your patience.
BR

Comment: I didn't suggest a join with the users table. Are you sure you tried my suggestion?

Comment: yes.. this is your solution:
see here:

[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e90bb/12]

As you can see news serviceID appears twice

Comment: yes, now it is what searching for.. I think have still to learn quite a lot about t-sql
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yeah, well, learning never stops in this line of work. they always come up with some new technology and you have to work hard just to keep up with times. I'm still learning new things almost every day after 16+ years as a programmer. Anyway, Glad to help.

Comment: hmm... I would not abuse your kindness, but in real world scenario I need to retrieve 3-4 fields from ActiveServices, but when I try to add them I receive an error: 
**Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

I bypassed the problem adding the other field at first  like here

[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c88fb/3]

But I was wondering how can get more fields in normal way

thanks again

Comment: yes.. that should give the required results..
but is relatively simple (I mean.. any uncommon commands for me except coalesce)..
That's frustrating for me since I've been struggling for days without any result.
Anyway, thanks a lot again
joe

Comment: Simple is good. The simpler a code is the better. I know it can be frustrating (i once spent over 4 hours for an sql that was throwing errors until my co-worker looked at it and found that it was missing a comma). Sometime all you need is a different perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
SELECT s.*,
  CASE WHEN (as.PaidUntil IS NOT NULL AND getDate() <= as.PaidUntil) 
     then 'ACTIVE ' + Cast(as.PaidUntil as varchar(20)) 
     else 'ACTIVATE' 
  end as State
FROM Services AS s
LEFT JOIN ActiveServices AS as 
   on as.ServiceID= s.ID
LEFT JOIN Users AS u 
   on as.UserId= u.ID
```

Comment: Hi!
yes, thanks, it works, although need to add **userID** filter within the CASE Statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to use left joins on this tables and use CASE statement to have correct result.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN (PaidUntil not is NULL AND getDate() <= PaidUntil) then 'ACTIVE ' + Cast(PaidUntil as varchar) else 'ACTIVATE' end as State
 FROM Services 
LEFT JOIN ActiveServices on ActiveServices.ServiceID= Services.ID
LEFT JOIN Users on ActiveServices.UserId= Users.ID
```

I didn't check syntax, but this is basically the way.

Comment: Hi yes.. there were a couple of syntax errors and missing userID filter but amended as follows it works well:
`declare @userID nvarchar(50)='test'   
    SELECT m.*,
  CASE WHEN (PaidUntil is not NULL AND getDate() <= PaidUntil and u.UID=@userID) then 'ACTIVE ' + Cast(PaidUntil as varchar) else 'ACTIVATE' end as State
 FROM modules m 
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s on s.modulecode= m.modulecode
LEFT JOIN Users u on s.UID= u.UID`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   @userid,
   s.*,
   ISNULL('ACTIVE ' + CAST(acs.PaidUntil as varchar(20)),  'ACTIVATE') as CurrentState
 FROM Services s
 LEFT JOIN ActiveServices acs
     ON s.ServiceID = acs.ServiceID
     AND acs.PaidUntil > DATE()
     AND acs.UserID = @userid
```

Basically you want all services available ... given the information provided that appears to be all services from the services table (not sure if Enabled column indicates exclusion of certain services)

The next criteria is does the service exist in the ActiveService table for the User specified and a PaidUntil date some point after the current date.  Since we already joined the service and ActiveService table on ServiceID we need to limit the result set returned by the ActiveService table for both of these factors.

Since the join is a left join we can limit it auch that the results returned by the ActiveService table will either be NULL or an ActiveService record.

EDIT: This should provide the optimized query result but I would be interested to see the query execution plan as compared to the CASE statements.

Comment: Hi!
yes, Enabled column means service is available and need to show all Enabled (available) Services: for the one the customer has subscribed, return expiry date (PaidUntil) for the other return empty value.
but if I have applied correctly your solution.. does not returned the required result: it returns only the services the customer has subscribed: if customer has not subscribed any service will return no record :-(

Comment: Please see revised post

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an outer join between `Services` and a relevant subset of `ActiveServices`. Since you want to filter `ActiveServices` *before* the join, you will need to specify the filter condition in the ON clause (rather than the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT
  s.ServiceID,
  s.Name,
  Status = CASE WHEN a.ServiceID IS NULL THEN 'Activate' ELSE 'Active' END,
  a.PaidUntil
FROM
  dbo.Services AS s
  LEFT JOIN dbo.ActiveServices AS a ON s.ServiceID = a.ServiceID
    AND a.UserID = @UserID
    AND a.PaidUntil >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)
;
```

The right side of the join will have matches only for active services of the specified user `@UserID` – you will just need to check if the right side's `ServiceID` is not null. (Actually, any non-nullable `ActiveServices` column would do.)